# Need to rotate (fluring) image using Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4.5

Please help me that, how to smoothly rotate(fling) one circle image clock wise as well as anticlockwise,

I tried many thing but not getting the proper result.

so please help me for this, Thanks in advance.

> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>     ij = 0;   rotatingDirection = 1;  additionalOffset = 0;   totalAnglesRotated = 0;     isInFlingMode = TRUE;   isOptionSelected =
>     FALSE;
>     viewAnimation.hidden = FALSE;     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>     selector:@selector(_handleWhateverChange) name:@"DataDownload"
>     object:nil];
>
>   panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];     [panRecognizer
>     setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];     [panRecognizer
>     setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];     [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
>     [imgViewdialer addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
>
>   ```
>   [self Imagesswipemethod];
>   ```
>
> }

```
-(void)move:(id)sender {
            //[[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

    CGPoint convertedPoint = [self.view.superview convertPoint:self.view.frame.origin toView:nil];
        // NSLog(@" Convert Point.. :: x = %f , y = %f",convertedPoint.x,convertedPoint.y);

            [imgViewdialer bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];         CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:view1.superview];   //  NSLog(@" trans values.. :: x
= %f , y = %f",translatedPoint.x,translatedPoint.y);

    int y=translatedPoint.y;
    int xx = translatedPoint.x;

        if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
                        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;          firstY = [[sender view] center].y;      }
                translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);
                if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                        if (isInFlingMode) {


                //NSLog(@"Completed");
                CGPoint vPoint = [panRecognizer velocityInView:imgViewdialer.superview];
                double point = [panRecognizer locationInView:view1].x;
                double pinty = [panRecognizer locationInView:view1].y;

                NSLog(@"touch Point y %f",pinty);
                NSLog(@"touch Point x %f",point);
                NSLog(@"Translate Point x %d",xx);
                NSLog(@"Translate Point y %d",y);




                float angleToBeRotated = (vPoint.x + vPoint.y) ;
                //(vPoint.x < 0) && (vPoint.y >= 0)) || ((vPoint.x < 0) && (vPoint.y < 0)
                if(point>160)
                {
                    if(y<0)
                        rotatingDirection = -1;
                    else if(y>0)
                        rotatingDirection = 1;

                } else {

                    if(y<0)
                        rotatingDirection = 1;
                    else if(y>0)
                        rotatingDirection = -1;
                }

                if(pinty > 200 && xx <0)
                    rotatingDirection = 1;
                else if(pinty >200 && xx>160)
                    rotatingDirection = -1;

                            //  rotatingDirection = 1;

                angleToBeRotated = (angleToBeRotated > 0) ? angleToBeRotated : (angleToBeRotated * -1);

                globalAngle = angleToBeRotated;

                ////NSLog(@"angleToBeRotated = %f", (globalAngle / 75.0));

                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(rotaterThreadMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
                        }       } else {
                /*  CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:view1];           ////NSLog(@"Current Point X = %f, Y = %f", translatedPoint.x + firstX, translatedPoint.y + firstY);             previousTouchPoint = CGPointMake(firstX, firstY);
                        if(!isOptionSelected) {
                CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([imgViewdialer bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([imgViewdialer bounds]));
                ////NSLog(@"Center Point X = %f, Y = %f", center.x, center.y);
                CGPoint currentTouchPoint = CGPointMake(translatedPoint.x , translatedPoint.y);
                CGFloat angleInRadians;
                if((previousTouchPoint.x != 0) && (previousTouchPoint.y != 0)) {
                    angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);
                }
                //previousTouchPoint = currentTouchPoint;
                CGFloat angleInDegree = RadianTodegrees(angleInRadians);

                angleInDegree = globalAngle+angleInDegree;
                [self rotateAccordingToAngle:degreesToRadian(angleInDegree)];

                revolutions+= (angleInDegree/360.0f);           }*/
                    }    }



- (void)rotateAccordingToAngle:(float) angle
{
    ////NSLog(@"Current Global Angle = %f", globalAngle);

    totalAnglesRotated += RadianTodegrees(angle);

    if(totalAnglesRotated >= 360)
        totalAnglesRotated -= 360;
    else if(totalAnglesRotated <= -360)
        totalAnglesRotated += 360;


    lblRotatingAngle.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalAnglesRotated] stringValue];

    [imgViewdialer setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(imgViewdialer.transform, angle)];
}
```

Comment: One hint try this method to make use of two gestures togather :- - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

Comment: Please post the things you've tried + code. If you're looking to "fling" the image and have it come to rest at a similar velocity as a scroll view, you might consider using a sort of ghost UIScrollView that accepts your gestures, and rotate the image based on the offset of the scroll view.

Comment: Okay, I have put my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Rotation Recognizer, this will help you :

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationrecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];

[rotationrecognizer setDelegate:self];


[img12 addGestureRecognizer:rotationrecognizer];
```

After this :

```
-(void)rotate:(id)sender
{

NSLog(@"rotate method called");


[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
}

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);


CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
            CGAffineTransform newTransform = 
CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);


[[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];


lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [Gesture Implementation](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/). Which I believe one of the best link for gesture.